# select single association from has_many through in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many-through

Is there any (clean) way to access a single association when using a has_many through association?

For example, to get all of a Recipe's Ingredients, I can write:

`@ingredients = @recipe.ingredients`

However, if I have an ingredient already selected, and I want to add data to the join table for the recipe/ingredient, I can't figure out the clean way to add the data.

I cannot access the single ingredient association's amount using

```
ingredient = Ingredient.find(an_id)  

amount = @recipe.ingredient.amount
```

What is the method of select a single ingredients information that is stored in the join table?

Comment: So you have found the Recipe you want, you have found the Ingredients for that Recipe. Do you want to edit the attributes of one of these Ingredients or do you want to add a new Ingredient for the previouslt selected Recipe? Or is there another Join table on Ingredients that you want to populate?

Comment: There is a join table on recipes and ingredients that holds information about ingredients specific to the recipe they are related to, i.e. amounts for each ingredient.

Answer (score 1):

Options `:select` is very useful in this case. For example

```
class Recipe
  has_many :ingredients, through: ingredients_recipes, select: "ingredinets.*, ingredients_recipes.some_additional_column as some_additional_column"
  ....
```

Then just call

```
Recipe.first.ingredients.first.some_additional_column # => profit!
```

You can use it in your scopes too.

Answer (score 0):

You could `@ingredient = @recipe.ingredients.first` (if it is truly the only one, not sure how you could know this for sure.)

Assuming you already have the ingredient selected, as in a variable, you can set them like any other ActiveRecord object.

```
@ingredient = @recipe.ingredients.first
@ingredient.amount = 15 #or @ingredient.amount = params[:amount] (if you get the new value from POST)
@ingredient.unit = "Ounces"
@ingredient.save
```

If you just want to retrieve the attributes of each ingredient for a recipe and do something with them, like display them in some html tags in a view you could try this.

```
@ingredients = @recipe.ingredients
   @ingredients.each do |ingr|
    info = %w[amount, brand, id, recipe_id , unit].map do |attr|
      ingr.send(attr)
    end
```

at the end of each inner loop the array 'info' will be all the attributes of one ingredient.(assuming you include them in info array)

This is an example of a table you might use to store the associations, it should work with the rails `:through => :recipe_ingedient` method:

```
CREATE TABLE `recipe_ingredient` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `recipe_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ingedient_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=59 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci$$
```

Comment: how do you want to access @recipe.ingeredient? this will throw a NameError "undefined method `ingredient' for #<Recipe:HASH>"

Comment: I understand the logic here behind selecting a single ingredient at a time, but I'm wondering what is the most efficient way to store data in the join table between recipes and ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

The join table is important for you, so it should have a name.
You can call it recipe_ingredient, but a real name helps not to confuse the things mentally. (and it help us discussing about the problem)

Given the join table is called for example `slot`.

```
class Recipe
  has_many :slots
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :slots
  ..
class Slot
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
  ...
```

You get a defined slot by calling

```
@slot = @recipe.slots.where(:ingredients_id => @ingredient).first 
@slot.amount = 20
```

For extra efficiency and to ensure that each combination exists only one time, you can define an unique compound index for slot to span across both recipe_id and ingredient_id

Answer (score -1):

I don't see how such a thing could exist. If you have *many* associated objects, you need to specify *which one* you want. That's not so much a limitation of Rails as a limitation of... I don't know, set theory? Logic?
You can get the one of the associated objects with `.first` (`ingredient = @recipe.ingredients.first`), but unless you also specify an order, there's no way to be certain which one it will be.

Comment: That's funny...set theory. It is completely within the limitations of the database and the has_many relation for either or both tables to only have one record(in the table itself or only one with matching keys). So obviously, it's not a limitation of anything. Go ahead and try it if you don't believe me.